# SQL Server Get only Date form column with Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have been trying to get only date from a column with date and time.

Here is a sample:

```
Select BDATE 
from PersonData
```

Current output:

```
1977-12-05 15:40:54.000
```

Desired output:

```
1977-12-05
```

How can I use the `CONVERT` date from datetime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. I select a column from a table. While the other person asks simply from a table? I think this post makes it easier to understand. If this is to be deleted it should at least be merged with the other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Cast`;

```
Select cast(BDATE as Date) BDATE from PersonData
```

Also, you can use `Convert` function

```
Select convert(Date,BDATE) BDATE from PersonData
```

If you don't want special conversation styles, I suggest you to use `Cast` instead of `Convert` for simple type conversations.

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BDATE , 120) from PersonData
```

style : 120  for ODBC canonical yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FORMAT like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT([BDATE],'yyy-MM-dd') AS 'BDATE' FROM PersonData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for the convert() function.

CONVERT(data_type(length), expression, style)

The **datatype** to convert expression to. Can be one of the following: bigint, int, smallint, tinyint, bit, decimal, numeric, money, smallmoney, float, real, datetime, smalldatetime, char, varchar, text, nchar, nvarchar, ntext, binary, varbinary, or image. Required filed.

The **length** of the resulting data type (for char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary and varbinary).Its and Optional.

The **Expression** value to convert to another data type. Required filed.

The **Style** format used to convert between data types, such as a date or string format.Its an Optional.

refer the below query to your answer,

```
   select CONVERT(date,BDATE) from PersonData
```

Refer the below link to various type of Convert Formation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql